# PHP Chart Library with ability to style background

Tags: php, charts, graphing

I am needing to set 3 color variants of the background of a line chart along the y-axis of a chart as (low=yellow, medium=orange and high=red).  Many offer background images, ability to change single background color, alternating rows, etc... Is there a charting library for php that allows for that level of customization along the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)?

Answer (score 0):

This will do...

http://code.google.com/p/mtchart/